# Need some help related to sha512

Tags: cryptography, sha, sha512, sha2

i want to get first character of original string from hashe sha512. The format of my original string
is it have 32 characters. first character in set of { 1, 2, 3, 4...9, T,J,Q,K }
the second character in set of { D, S, H, C }
the third character is "-"
and last characters in set of { a to z, A to Z, 0 to 9 }
i want input is "e9353e5aa1dedb3eb4767da8d21b81d7dbf10fa8f23e4704084c989edf5293a46f41f8b3c77c6f828ccf1f688585a52fe0b0601b0c2485af656579bb9b5cd48f"
this is hashed string of "1S-74iaoSurg6nVxMzkqwVQMcmWvzmpP"

i want output is "1"

I will be grateful if somebody help me out in this.
Thanks

Comment: You'd have to test all possible input combinations until you find one with the same hash. That should be fine if you have about 10^40 years of computing power available at 1 million guesses per second.

Comment: is there not any easy way...?

Comment: Of course not, this is a hash, and a modern one. If there was an easy way, it would be really broken.

Comment: actually i'm working on a project and this is my ultimate motive...it seems impossible then

Comment: This sounds like a [XY problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Explain what you want to achieve, don't ask how to break a modern hash function.

Comment: If each of your remaining 29 characters { a to z, A to Z, 0 to 9 }  has equal probability, brute force will not work (any time soon), but if that last part of the message has some structure you could reduce your search space.

Answer (score 2):

You can only get the input for the output of a one-way hash function by trying every input value (if possible in the order of likelihood).

There are 13 options for that first character, 4 for the next one, and 62 characters in the final 29 characters of the string. We can disregard the single dash.

That makes `13 * 4 * 62 ^ 29 = ~5 × 10^53` possibilities to test. So if this is all you have that makes this impossible to solve. It's equivalent to breaking a 178 bit AES key (calculate by taking the 2-log of the number of possibilities, or by dividing 53 by about 3 and then multiplying with 10 for a quick approximation), if such a thing would exist.

Comment: Log<sub>2</sub>(13 * 4 * 62 ^ 29)+1 ~= 179. log2 bits requires an addition. There is a \lfoor that I cannot write here.

Comment: It's over 128, that's all that's important here :P. Um, sorry, better round *down* when it comes to estimating strength. Or explain the +1?